# How to connect tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

How to connect tags:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/passport/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/passport.js/info and its synonym: `passportjs`

Descriptions are identical.

Comment: A lot of these are about Laravel Passport. The description is merely wrong. More still are about Facebook-passport integration (for which there is a separate tag), etc.

Comment: We can retag [these 374 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport+node.js+-passport.js) to `passport.js`, because they are just mis-tagged. Same for the [laravel passport posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport+laravel), etc.

Comment: I'm filtering out the posts that are not about passport.js, retagging those, and then I'll merge the remainder (with no synonym). That'll burninate the confusing `passport` tag entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In this case.**
The tags are not synonyms of each other. [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) is (also) commonly used for [Laravel Passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport) (should be tagged [laravel-passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-passport)), which is completely different from [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/).

---

**In general.**
You can [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) that [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) is a synonym of [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/passport.js/synonyms). You do need 5 score in the tag to be able to do so. The reason is that you need to be certain that the two tags are in fact synonyms.

Once suggested, others will be able to vote for the synonym.

Note that a synonym [passportjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passportjs) → [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js) already exists.

Answer (score 7):

The `passport` tag is gone now.

It was just a duplicate tag, and because it was using the generic name *passport*, it was being used for several different meanings:

- about 3 posts involving reading passport data. These did not need the tag
- A largish pile of Laravel / PHP posts using the [Laravel Passport API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport). I've retagged these to use [laravel-passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-passport)
- for the [passport.js framework](http://www.passportjs.org/), in combination with a host of Javascript frameworks.

I've cleaned up the first two categories, verified there were only Javascript uses left (by filtering out the javascript tags, such as `node.js`, `express`, `javascript`, `jwt`, and `reactjs`) and then merged the `passport` tag into `passport.js`.

This was not the first time we had to do this, it may be time to blacklist the tag, so the Community Managers have now blacklisted the tag. When you try to use it anyway, you are given the following message:

[image: passport tag block]